# Rails 4 raises ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)): when updating through AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I want to update the `status` of the notifications to `read` whenever I want the user clicks on the notification dropdown of the app.

Here is the controller code:

```
class Api::V1::NotificationsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @notifications = Notification.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(created_at: :desc)

    render_success @notifications
  end

  def create
    Notification.update_all({status: "read"}, {user_id: current_user.id})
  end

end
```

and the jQuery code that should trigger the `create` method for the controller:

```
$('.notifications-menu').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('Opened notifications');
  $.post('/api/v1/notifications');
})
```

Unfortunately, it returns this error:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/notifications" for ::1 at 2017-09-19 16:27:53 +0800
Processing by Api::V1::NotificationsController#create as */*
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  app/controllers/api/v1/notifications_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `create` method to this:

```
def create
  Notification.update_all(status: "read", user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :) Will choose this as the accepted answer in 10 minutes

Comment: Glad to help you )